# Java file directory (filter)

Tags: java

I want to filter out a specific type of file from a directory but I get the error 'syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens':

```
    File dir = new File("c:/etc/etc");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
       public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
           return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
}
});
```

I also get a bunch of other errors, really confused.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting, and what line is it coming from?

Comment: first two lines I get 'delete these tokens' and '( expected after this token' after accept.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine (bar the misindentation on the last two lines), we will need some more context to figure out the problem here.

Comment: I dont see any issues or errors on the program you posted here.

Comment: Apologies I had commented out some important bits of code that's why it resulted in those errors. I fixed that. But now I get 'dirr' and 'files' underlined in yellow and as a result nothing shows up when I run the program. What would I need to do?

Comment: It says local variable not used.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you could use lambda expression but that will not solve your problem. I dont see any errors or issues with the code you have posted here.

```
File dir = new File("c:/etc/etc");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles((File dir1, String name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"));
```

Comment: Apologies I had commented out some important bits of code that's why it resulted in those errors. But now I get 'dirr' and 'files' underlined in yellow and as a result nothing shows up when I run the program. What would I need to do? The yellow warnings say local variable not used..

Comment: Unless we have the full code to view no idea whats that error was. from the error it looks like you are using  variable assignment in if loop like this (dirr = true)

Comment: ohh that's the entire code to filter out the .txt files. The error was due to commenting out the main method accidentally. But with the errors gone some of the variables such as dirr are underlined yellow becuase its not used. I wonder how I can use it so that it the .txt files are filtered